# Spring add cache to existing CacheManager bean

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-bean, spring-cache

I have an application which depends on a library. The application may or may not have a bean of type CacheManager. The libraries internal kitchen uses caching as well. Therefor it must use the existing bean of the application, or create one of its own with caches A,B,C. If the library uses the existing bean, then it must enrich that bean with caches A,B,C. How on earth do i do this?

I've tried adding the following code into the library, for the part 'create when none exists'

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(CacheManager.class)
public CacheManager codPlusCacheManager() {
    SimpleCacheManager cacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
    cacheManager.setCaches(Arrays.asList(
        new ConcurrentMapCache("A"),
        new ConcurrentMapCache("B"),
        new ConcurrentMapCache("C")))
    return cacheManager;
}
```

How can i enrich an existing bean?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to enrich an existing, you can have both beans living side by side.
In order to do that you can use spring caching and to determine what will be your cache manager.
e.g:

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("libCacheManager")
public JCacheCacheManager libCacheManager() {
    // Details Omitted.
}
```

And then on your cacheable method use:

```
@Cacheable(cacheManager = "libCacheManager", cacheNames = "name")
```

Comment: This works. But application startup fails if no bean with id "cacheManager" exists, even if a CacheManager with another name exists. (at least in my project). Do I now create a bean with id cacheManager in my library project? If I do, it may clash with a bean from the project that uses the library. If I don't, startup will fail if the project that uses the library doesn't declare a bean with id cacheManager. Do you have a solution?

Comment: It would be hard to understand exactly how the "cacheManager" is being used, you can always add an additional @ConditionalOn... in order to use the cache manager with the name cachemanager in case that is required in your application

Comment: To clarify my previous comment: I was using the <cache:annotation-driven> xml configuration which assumes the existence of bean named cacheManager, whereas the java EnableCaching annotation assumes the existence of a bean of type CacheManager. So your answer works fine for java configuration which is what was posted in the question. Unfortunately for me there is no equivalent (as far as I know) for the ConditionalOn... annotations for xml configuration, so I can't fix my case that way. I'll just switch to java config, which I like better anyway.

Answer (score -1):

According to the [api specification](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/support/SimpleCacheManager.html#setCaches-java.util.Collection-) of `setCaches()` it requires a collection of cache objects. Please try the following approach to configure your cache-manager:

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(CacheManager.class)
public CacheManager codPlusCacheManager() {
    SimpleCacheManager cacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
    Collection<Cache> caches = Arrays.asList(
        new ConcurrentMapCache("A"),
        new ConcurrentMapCache("B")
        new ConcurrentMapCache("C")

    ); 
    cacheManager.setCaches(caches);
    return cacheManager;
}
```

Comment: This answer is about the part I already know. The part I need is how to enrich an existing bean. I deleted some of the code for purposes.